# Highcharts adding labels/columns with no data

Tags: highcharts

I'm having a problem with Highcharts drawing points that have no data attached to them. The chart is a column chart with drilldown, showing an average "time" per week on the top level, with a drilldown displaying the actual value per case for the selected week.

My problem is this: When I drill down into a certain week, cases that do not exist are still displayed on the chart if they exist between two existing case IDs.e.

Consider the data being passed for week 6: [[272, 25.07][297, 500.54]], only two cases exist: 272 and 297. However, Highcharts is giving me this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpABB.png

This is the code for the chart itself:

```
                Highcharts.chart('DrilldownChart', {
                chart: {
                    type: 'column'
                },
                title: {
                    text: ''
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: ''
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: "",
                    labels: {
                        rotation: 90
                    },
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: ''
                    }

                },
                exporting: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                legend: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    column: {
                        minPointLength: 0
                    },
                    series: {
                        borderWidth: 0,
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: false,
                            format: '{point.y:.1f}',
                            rotation: 270
                        }
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{#000}"></span>{point.y:.2f}<br/>'
                },

                series: MainDataArray,
                drilldown: {
                    series: DrilldownDataArray,
                }

            });
```

Does anyone know how to stop it from drawing the labels/columns between points with actual data?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example (e.g.: jsfiddle), it'll be easier to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to convert the `x` values from your array to `String` type, then they would be treated as a category name instead of category indexes. In order to convert it, you can use `Array.map()` function just like that:

```
var drilldownSeries = [{
    id: 'One',
    data: [[272, 25.07], [297, 500.54]].map(elem => {
        return [elem[0].toString(), elem[1]]
    })
  }]
```

However, before that please make sure that your `xAxis.type` is set to `'category'`, because I noticed that in your code there is an empty string assigned to `type` field.

Here is the example which shows how to achieve described effect:
https://jsfiddle.net/8h03urrr/

Comment: Thank you, that works!

There is one issue however after I changed the caseIDs to strings:

https://imgur.com/h35QBrt

The categories are only caseIDs corresponding to the actual amount of weeks I've got data on (Data-array has 17 entries/weeks). This only happens on Week 12 however, so I imagine it might be because this week has a lot more data than others? Week 12 has 97 entries that look like this:  

https://imgur.com/RJd0AZV

Other weeks that have up to  50 entries are fine.

Comment: So, could you provide me with some minimal working example?

Comment: Sure thing, I printed out the arrays and added them to a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/xxnL32tp/6/ 

The issue I'm talking about happens on week 12, the chart starts using array indexes instead of case IDs for labels from index 17 and onwards. The second largest array, week 14, causes no such issue.

Comment: Thank you for provided demo. It's a most encountered problem with charts which has many categories and drilldown module included. You need to set the `plotOptions.series.cropThreshold` equal to a number larger than the points in a drilldown series.
Here is the link to reported issue on GitHub: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5857 , and also
fixed example: https://jsfiddle.net/hygn8xe9/